# What is the best way to store photo related data in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I need to store some Photo related information for my app. I understand that you can read/write GPS location and image description already to the Image Content Provider.

I would also need to add fields (flags) for cloud synchronization, i.e. with 'UPDATING' and "NEEDS SYNCING"... etc

Can I add additional columns to the default Image Content Provider to store these flags? If not what is the best way to store them?

I was thinking about setting up my own SQLite Table, but as I only need to store one or two fields for these flags, it seems to me an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with the `SharedPreferences` short, simple and sweet. The only thing you need to take care of is the key which is referring to the tag value and required for shared preferences.

You can learn on that from this link, http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Comment: SharedPreferences seems to be a good choice. I'm trying to integrate it with a Sync Adapter now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146272/sync-adapter-without-account